# Python keeps saying invalid syntax

Tags: syntax

I'm currently trying to correct a code for a class and I when I try to the run the module it keeps saying invalid syntax. Please Help!

This is the code.

print (myName + ',thank you for taking this quiz. Your score was ' + myScore 'out of 3. ')

Comment: What is myName and myScore? Strings? if not you need to convert to string, like `str(myScore)`, and after myScore is missing a +...

Answer (score 0):

```
myName = "Jay"
myScore = 1
print ('%s thank you for taking this quiz. Your score was out %d of 3. ') %(myName, myScore)
```

This is a better way do it. The reason your code doesn't work is because you are missing a '+' after myScore.

```
print (myName + ',thank you for taking this quiz. Your score was ' + myScore +  'out of 3. ')
```

That is the corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

Think deeper, your thought should think what syntax error you just made, not focus on a missing of a '+'